# How do I prove exponent rules for all real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, alternative-proof

It is easy to prove exponent rules for only the positive integers. For example, a^m.a^n = (a.a.a.a...)m times . (a.a.a.a.a....)n times so we just add the exponents m and n to get a^m+n. But how do I apply the same logic on rational or irrational or negative exponents ? How do I prove that these laws of exponents work for all real numbers NOT only just the positive integers ? for example (a.b)^n = a^n.b^n or any other law of exponents.

Comment: This is a central and really important question, and there are several possibilities to do this. Unfortunately, this is not the right place to ask this. Sorry. Look up some beginning analysis books/lectures.

Comment: Can you please recommend a book to me ?

Comment: Note that $m,n$ will be real, but $a$ will be positive. You don't extend the property $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$ for all reals $a,m,n$. It doesn't work in that generality.

Comment: The first thing is to define what is $a^n$. One way is to define $a^n=e^{n\log(a)}$, define $e^x=\sum_nx^n/n!$ and $\log(x)=\int_{1}^{x}dt/t$. Then you prove that $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ by either checking that both sides converge to the same thing, or that they satisfy the same differential equation with initial condition.

Comment: This wiki page can get you started.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation you can scroll down to "rational exponents" or "real exponents." There are tons of references at the bottom, but many ordinary Calculus texts will discuss this topic.

Comment: Start reading a book on analysis. Then you'll be able to see the vast machinery used to prove those laws

Comment: I think people might see the case of natural numbers and oversimplify the matter a bit. No, even the meaning of what $a^r$ is for $a > 0$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is not that easy to define without any background. We just assume those things because we like to use our intuition and things we were told.

Comment: @OliverHall See Section 3.3 in Laczkovich-T. Sós: Real Analysis https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-2766-1

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, as already mentioned in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1198684/ndb), is to begin by defining the exponential function by
$$\exp(x) = 1 + x + {x^2\over 2!} + {x^3\over 3!} + {x^4 \over 4!} + \cdots$$
for any real (or even complex) $x$.  Then $\log(x)$ is defined to be the inverse of $\exp(x)$, and exponentiation is defined by
$$ a^b := \exp(b \log(a)).$$
The rules of exponents can then be proved by reasoning with the power series of the exponential function.

Contrary to what some commenters have suggested, I do not think that it is easy to find a readable, self-contained account of all the details required to flesh out the above sketch.  I would suggest starting with the Prologue to Walter Rudin's book *Real and Complex Analysis*. This is rather terse but it does at least sketch the main steps.

Another approach, which avoids the exponential function, is sketched in Exercise 6 of Chapter 1 of Rudin's book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  This approach first carefully defines what $a^n$ (and therefore $a^{1/n}$) means for any real $a$ and any positive integer $n$. Then it defines $a^b$ to be the least upper bound of all numbers $a^t$ where $t$ is a rational number less than $b$.  The advantage of this approach is that you can see more explicitly how to build up everything step by step from the axioms for the real numbers.  But  it's the definition in terms of the exponential function that is ultimately more useful in practice.

Comment: How do you prove that a^b=exp(blog(a))

Comment: @OliverHall First one proves that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. By an induction argument, this implies that $\exp(nx) = (\exp(x))^n$ for positive real $x$ and positive integers $n$. If we define $a = \exp(x)$ so that $x = \log(a)$, we can rewrite the identity  $\exp(nx) = (\exp(x))^n$ as $\exp(n\log(a)) = a^n$. This shows that $a^b = \exp(b\log(a))$ for positive real numbers $a$ and positive integers $b$. Similar arguments can extend the result to rational numbers $b$. So this shows that the "new" definition coincides with the "old" definition.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: Given $n\in N, x,c\in R, c>0, x^n=c$ has at least 1 solution over the reals.

Let $A=\{x\in R| x^n\le c\}$

$\forall n, 0^n=0<c \implies 0\in  A$.

If $c=1$, $x=1$ and we have our solution.

Let $x,y \in R, 0<x<y.   $

$x^2<xy.$

$xy<y^2$

So $x^2<y^2$.

More generally $x<y\implies x^n<y^n$.

If $c<1$ and $x<c$, $x^n<x<c<1$ so $A$ is bounded above by 1.

If $1<c, c<x, c<c^n<x^n, so \ x\notin A.$ So $x\le c$. So $A$ is bounded above by $c$.

So either $c=1$ or A is bounded above by 1 or $c$. By the Least Upper Bound property of the reals a non-empty subset that is bounded above has a least upper bound. The least upper bound of A is the root we seek. And it thus makes sense to let $x=c^{1/n}$. From there we have $m\in N, x^m=c^{m/n}$ by the usual exponent rules. We now have a definition for raising to a rational power.

By the Archimidean Property  $\forall r\in R, n \in N, \exists m/n \in Q| m/n<r<(m+1)/n$.

$n$ can be made arbitrarily small and whatever value we assign to $a^r$ it's difference from $a^{m/n}$ can be made arbitrarily small. This allows assigning it a value of the limit of a base raised to a sequence of rational numbers.